# z-index doesn't work with absolute elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, absolute

When we have some `absolute` DIVs in page and one `fixed` DIV as a child of one of those `absolute` DIVs that has bigger `z-index` than those `absolute` DIVs, the `fixed` DIV goes behind of `absolute` DIVs!

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3qRaR/1/

HTML:

```
<div class='l1'>
    <div class='data'></div>
</div>
<div class='l1'>
    <div class='data'></div>
</div>
<div class='l1'>
    <div class='data'></div>
</div>
<div class='l1'>
    <div class='data'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.l1{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index:1001;
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.l1:nth-child(1){
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
.l1:nth-child(2){
    left: 110px;
    top: 5px;
}
.l1:nth-child(3){
    left: 220px;
    top: 5px;
}
.l1:nth-child(4){
    left: 330px;
    top: 5px;
}
.data{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:2000;
    background: black;
}
.l1:first-child .data{
    display: block;
}
```

Why?
**How can I make it to go to the front of them?**

Thanks

Comment: Your markup is flawed.  How can you have something `fixed` (relative to the window) **inside** an element that is `absolute` (relative to the document)?  If you want it in front, move it *outside* of the parent container.

Comment: @cale_b: i'm going to templorary maximize a div from another div to fill the entire page as a full screen view

Comment: Again, that's **not** how you should do it.

Comment: Use absolute positioning then.  Not fixed.

Comment: @cale_b: absolute position causes the filling of the parent DIV but I don't want to fill the parent; i want to fill the page (i.e. the viewport)!

Comment: *Then change your markup*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the z-index from the `.li` rule and the black .data div will sit ontop of the yellow .li divs. I am assuming that is what you are trying to do?

```
.l1{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    // Removed the z-index from here
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; yes that works but it causes another problem that the DIVs will go behind of other elements in page!

Comment: Using absolute and fixed positing like this will ultimately create a lot of hard-to-manage css issues for you. Depending on your goal, you would be better off using relative or static positioning (static is the default position value) and reserving the fixed positing for the big full-screen overlay when you expand .data.

Answer (score 0):

`fixed` makes divs `fixed` to document, not the element, even if it is `absolute`. Make .data divs of position `absolute`, not `fixed`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3qRaR/7/

```
.data{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:2000;
    background: black;
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want that `fixed` div to cover the entire document then just make the `fixed` div's container higher `z-index` than the rest:

http://jsfiddle.net/3qRaR/11/

```
.l1:nth-child(1){
    z-index: 10000;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for concept, but you've got something *wrong*.  Fixed makes div fixed to *window*, not to website.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to fill the parent; i want to fill the page (i.e. the viewport)!